# remove under scores in java files generated using xjc command

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xjc

I have the following lines in my xsd schema

```
<simpleType name="IdTypeEnum">
    <restriction base="token">
    <enumeration value="SIP1"></enumeration>
        <enumeration value="SIP2"></enumeration>
```

In generated java files, I have the following code

```
@XmlEnumValue("SIP2")
SIP_2("SIP2"),
@XmlEnumValue("CUSIP3")
SIP_3("SIP3"),
```

I want to remove the underscores in generated java files so that the above code looks like this

```
 @XmlEnumValue("SIP2")
SIP2("SIP2"),
@XmlEnumValue("CUSIP3")
SIP3("SIP3"),
```

Is there any way in which we can tweak the xjc command so that it generates java files in above manner?

My schema uses `elementFormDefault="qualified"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* change the names you want for the enumeration members. There are two ways of doing that:

1. JAXB mappings file
2. XSD annotations

#### Using XSD annotations

If you can modify your schema, you can insert JAXB elements as an `<xs:appinfo>` extension:

```
<simpleType name="IdTypeEnum">
    <restriction base="token">
        <enumeration value="SIP1">
            <annotation>
                <appinfo>
                    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="SIP1" />
                </appinfo>
            </annotation>
        </enumeration>
        <enumeration value="SIP2">
            <annotation>
                <appinfo>
                    <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="SIP2" />
                </appinfo>
            </annotation>
        </enumeration>
        ...
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

This should generate:

```
@XmlEnum
public enum IdTypeEnum {
    SIP1,
    SIP2;
    ...
```

without any `@XmlEnumValue` annotations since now they have identical names.

#### Using a bindings file

If you can't change the schema, you can also do that using *JAXB bindings*:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="sip.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='IdTypeEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='SIP1']">
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="SIP1"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='IdTypeEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='SIP2']">
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="SIP2"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And include the *bindings file* when you run `xjc`:

```
xjc -b bindings-file.xml sip.xsd
```

#### Generating a bindings files with XSLT

If you don't want to copy the same values individually it would be very simple to generate the *bindings* file using XSLT. Here's an example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/"> <!-- this templates sets the bindings file structure -->
        <jaxb:bindings version="2.0">
            <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="sip.xsd">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:simpleType[@name='IdTypeEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration"/>
            </jaxb:bindings>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:enumeration"> <!-- this template creates a bindings block -->
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='IdTypeEnum']/xs:restriction/xs:enumeration[@value='{@value}']">
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="{@value}"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can test it in this [XSLT Fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/6qM2e2r) and possibly also use it to generate your bindings file.

---

I'm not sure why `xjc` automatically introduced an underscore in your *enum* since it wasn't necessary. It usually does that when the enums would generate illegal Java identifiers (such as starting with numbers, containing dashes, etc.) It's probably using some algorithm based on *Java coding conventions* (where and Java enums and constants are usually in upper-case, with different words separated by underscores). It probably considers the `SIP` and the number as different words.

Comment: There are too many values to include individually .. also I cannot modify the schema file

Comment: You can use a bindings file. I added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton, will surely try this out.